# How to detect if ondraglistener is already finish? (android)

Tags: java, android, listener, gravity

I need to stop this service after a listener is already activated by using stopSelf(); However the service ends even though there is no Drag event... How can i detect if there is a Drag event happend before I can call StopService?

```
           mainButton.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
           vTopLeft.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
           vTopRight.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
           vBottomLeft.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
           vBottomRight.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
           Log.d("tok", "add mview");
           stopSelf(); ---> this should wait after draglistener is finish.
```

MyDragListener.java

```
Public class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener  {


@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    String containerName = null;
    int ID = 0;
    int Dragaction = event.getAction();
    int gravity2 = 1234567879;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            owner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) v;
            container.addView(view);

            LocationSerializable ls = new LocationSerializable();
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.topLeft:


                    gravity2 = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;

                    ls.setGravity(gravity2);
                    break;

                case R.id.topRight:

                    gravity2 = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
                    ls.setGravity(gravity2);
                    break;

                case R.id.bottomLeft:
                    gravity2= Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
                    ls.setGravity(gravity2);

                    break;
                case R.id.bottomRight:
                    gravity2 = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
                    ls.setGravity(gravity2);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown ID");
            }

            LinearLayout containerParent = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();

            LinearLayout conatainerGrandMother = (LinearLayout) containerParent.getParent();

            conatainerGrandMother.setVisibility(View.GONE);




        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

        default:


            break;
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop your service in  `case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:`

below is a sample template.

```
 @Override
      public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // do nothing
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        

          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
          // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup

          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
         // option 1
          Context.stopService();
           // option 2
            // stopService(new Intent(Activity.this,MailService.class));
           //stopSelf();
            //  other alternative is
             //  v.getContext().stopService(new Intent(v.getContext(),DragDropButtonMainService.class));
          break;
        }
        return true;
      }
```

According to [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

> After the user releases the drag shadow, and after the system sends out (if necessary) a drag event with action type ACTION_DROP, the system sends out a drag event with action type ACTION_DRAG_ENDED to indicate that the drag operation is over.

Comment: Thankyou but there is no stopSelf() in my MyDragListener(). I will post the code here.. it only implements view.ondraglistener.

Comment: My requirement is during Action_Drop or ACTION_DRAG_ENDED, I need to stop my service... your answer is good but stopself() is not found in the MyDragListener...

Comment: stopself() is not found in the MyDragListener i am not getting this > Are you  unable to call this method ?

Comment: yes... there is no stopself method in MyDragListener because it does not extend Service..... @Brontok

Comment: Yes... stopself() can only be used inside the service. What I am thinking is to have a stopself() in mydraglistener class, or if their is a way to know if listener is already finish then stopself() on the service itself.

Comment: stopSelf() is used in a service not in Activity. Inside the service you can call stopSelf().

Comment: I typed Context then after pressing the period, I could not see any stopService()...

Comment: Try using stopService(new Intent(Activity.this,MailService.class)); pass your parameters into this method.

Comment: There is no stopServirce method.. maybe i will extend it to Activity?

Comment: It does not work.. null pointer exception... I tried to even call the oncreate(new Bundle())...

Comment: I had solve it because of your idea. :) thanks.. This is the clue you have gave me..  stopService(new Intent(Activity.this,MailService.class)); This will work if you use the context of the view... tnx tnx. I will give you the answer score.. just add this on the code you write on your answer...   v.getContext().stopService(new Intent(v.getContext(),DragDropButtonMainService.class));